# Compiling OpenCV project using CMake results in build errors while regular compilation works fine

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, cmake, ld

I downloaded CMake and OpenCV using homebrew, I am trying to run a simple openCV program that opens my camera and starts to stream a video. I can compile my program regularly using the command line with:
`clang++ -std=c++11 lib_cpp.cpp -o execute 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4'`
However when I try to build and compile my project using CMake I am running into trouble and errors.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SDK=/Users/David/Library/Android/sdk
CMAKE=$SDK/cmake/3.18.1/bin/cmake
NDK=$SDK/ndk/23.0.7272597
TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
TOOLCHAIN_BINARIES=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
LD=$TOOLCHAIN_BINARIES/ld
ABI=arm64-v8a
MIN_SDK=16
STL=c++_shared
STD=-std=c++11 -o 
CXX=$TOOLCHAIN_BINARIES/aarch64-linux-android30-clang++
CMAKE_ARGS=""

export CXX=$CXX

$CMAKE -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=$STD -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$TOOLCHAIN_FILE -DANDROID_ABI=$ABI -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=$MIN_SDK -DANDROID_STL=$STL $CMAKE_ARGS
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)

project(shared_library_cpp VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_1/lib/cmake/opencv4")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(shared_library_cpp SHARED lib_cpp.cpp cpp.def)
add_executable(cpp_exec lib_cpp.cpp)
target_link_libraries( shared_library_cpp ${OpenCV_LIBS} )


set_target_properties(shared_library_cpp PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER lib_cpp.h
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SOVERSION 1
    OUTPUT_NAME "cpp"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "MacOS_ID"
)
```

For some reason I am getting a linkage problem, the script runs smoothly but when running `make` I am getting an error in the middle of the build

script output:

```
./create_makefile.sh: line 12: -o: command not found
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Warning at /Users/David/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7272597/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
  An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
  compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
  values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
  CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/David/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7272597/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
  /Users/David/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:93 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
CMake Warning at /Users/David/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7272597/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
  An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
  compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
  values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
  CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/David/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7272597/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
  /Users/David/Desktop/CPP/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  /Users/David/Desktop/CPP/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/David/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7272597/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_1 (found version "4.5.2") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/David/Desktop/CPP
```

error output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target cpp_exec
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cpp_exec
ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int, int)
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:22
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:23
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::Mat::Mat()
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:27
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:28
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::imshow(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:29
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::waitKey(int)
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:31
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::Mat::~Mat()
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:33
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:33
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)

ld: error: undefined symbol: cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:36
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)
>>> referenced by lib_cpp.cpp:36
>>>               CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/lib_cpp.cpp.o:(startVideo)
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [cpp_exec] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_exec.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you read the output which was conveniently put there by the `CMake` devs and did you follow it's advice? Did you add your `cv` library?

Comment: You link with OpenCV the **library** `mvu_shared_library_cpp`. But the error message is about **executable** `mvu_cpp_exec`, which is not linked.

Comment: I have read the comments but found no advice to follow, I might not understand what to do from what is written. I have add cv library.

Comment: About linking the library and not the executable, when linking to the executable I get different errors.

such as: ld: error: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_1/lib/libopencv_gapi.4.5.2.dylib: unknown file type

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found the solution to this problem. I was trying to compile my program for arm64 but the dylibs were compiled for x86-64. Downloading the sources from OpenCV, and giving the path to arm64 libraries solved this.